# How to convert milliseconds into Days/hours/minutes

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

I am calculating the hours,minutes using the milliseconds. Below is mycode

```
function getDuration(milli){
  let minutes = Math.floor(milli / 60000);
  let hours = Math.round(minutes / 60);
}
```

I want to display the user the time as 'Days' if hours > 24 , 'minutes' if minute < 60. How can i implement it in template string in the following format

```
setHtml('Duration', `${getDuration(user[0].milli_seconds)} <span id="days">Hours</span> <span>Minutes</span>`);
```

Comment: `new Date()` accepts miliseconds as single parameter `new Date(miliseconds)`. You can just omit the date part and use its time functionality. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Date object calculates the browser time. I am getting the milliseconds from an external API. i am calculating hours and minutes using those milliseconds. I don't want to display time i just need to display the Days/hours/minutes

Comment: Ah I see. My bad.

Comment: No problem. I am struggling to calculate and display it on the conditions as i mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return it as an object which returns days, hours or minutes depending on what is there.

```js
function getDuration(milli){
  let minutes = Math.floor(milli / 60000);
  let hours = Math.round(minutes / 60);
  let days = Math.round(hours / 24);

  return (
    (days && {value: days, unit: 'days'}) ||
    (hours && {value: hours, unit: 'hours'}) ||
    {value: minutes, unit: 'minutes'}
  )
};

var tDuration = getDuration(23456576210);

console.log(tDuration.value + ': ' + tDuration.unit);
```

### Original version:

```js
function getDuration(milli){
  let minutes = Math.floor(milli / 60000);
  let hours = Math.round(minutes / 60);
  let days = Math.round(hours / 24);

  return (
    (days && {days: days}) ||
    (hours && {hours: hours}) ||
    {minutes: minutes}
  )
};

var tDuration = getDuration(23456576210);

console.log(tDuration);
```

Comment: @Neo: Changed it a bit, guess this one suits your purpose better.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Accepted it. However where iam stuck is at the template string. since iam new to ES6. iam struggling to put a condition to check whether to display it as Days/hours/minutes
`setHtml('Duration',` `${getDuration(user[0].milli_seconds)} <span id="days">Hours</span> <span>Minutes</span>``);`

Comment: can you share your previous answer as well? before you edited it

Comment: @Neo: Yes, I put it back in. With the second solution you do not required any condition string anymore. Just build it according to the object.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate days first , then hours and minutes

```js
function convertToDays(milliSeconds){
let days = Math.floor(milliSeconds/(86400 * 1000));
milliSeconds -= days*(86400*1000);
let hours = Math.floor(milliSeconds/(60 * 60 * 1000 ));
milliSeconds -= hours * (60 * 60 * 1000);
let minutes = Math.floor(milliSeconds/(60 * 1000));
return {
  days,hours,minutes
} 
  
}

console.log(convertToDays(8640000));
```

Comment: How can i check it in template string and siplay accordingly 

`setHtml('Duration',` `${getDuration(user[0].milli_seconds)} <span id="days">Hours</span> <span>Minutes</span>``);`

Comment: I did not understoof the setHtml  method. Assuming you are using jquery, you can use as
let res = convertToDays(8640000);
$("p").html(`<span id="days">${res.days} days</span> <span id="hours">${res.hours}</span><span id="minutes">${res.minutes}</span> `)