# Convert milliseconds to hours or minute or hour or day in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert milliseconds to ...(sec/min/hours/day) ago,
I have tried like the below code but I am not getting the expected result, the output is showing that `19143.4 Days`. It should be 2 or 3 days.

```js
function msToTime(ms) {
  let seconds = (ms / 1000).toFixed(1);
  let minutes = (ms / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);
  let hours = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);
  let days = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
  if (seconds < 60) return seconds + " Sec";
  else if (minutes < 60) return minutes + " Min";
  else if (hours < 24) return hours + " Hrs";
  else return days + " Days"
}
console.log(msToTime(1653991056493))
```

Comment: Use moment-js or similar (https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Thank you but I want to do it without using any package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format time since xxx e.g. “4 minutes ago” similar to Stack Exchange sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177836/how-to-format-time-since-xxx-e-g-4-minutes-ago-similar-to-stack-exchange-site)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 1653991056493 ms are exactly 19143.4 days

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert milliseconds into Days/hours/minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478970/how-to-convert-milliseconds-into-days-hours-minutes)

Comment: I saw all the codes but all the codes gave me same output, but if I console this `new Date(1653991056493)` the output is `Tue May 31 2022 15:57:36 GMT+0600` which is 2 days ago

Comment: The time is calculated from `Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100` wich was 19143.4 days before `Tue May 31 2022 15:57:36 GMT+0600` so your code seems to work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact here your code seems to work fine.

Reading the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation :

> JavaScript Date objects represent a single moment in time in a platform-independent format. Date objects contain a Number that represents milliseconds since 1 January 1970 UTC.

So when you're doing `new Date(1653991056493)` it's 1653991056493ms after Jan 1st 1970 which is **19143.4 days**.

---

If you want the ms between a date and the current date, you can just substract the current date with the timestamp

```js
new Date() - 1653991056493
```

---

```js
function msToTime(ms) {
  let seconds = (ms / 1000).toFixed(1);
  let minutes = (ms / (1000 * 60)).toFixed(1);
  let hours = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toFixed(1);
  let days = (ms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toFixed(1);
  if (seconds < 60) return seconds + " Sec";
  else if (minutes < 60) return minutes + " Min";
  else if (hours < 24) return hours + " Hrs";
  else return days + " Days"
}
console.log(msToTime(new Date() - 1653991056493))
```

Answer (score 1):

I interpretted the question slightly differently to the accepted answer and am posting this as it might help people seeking to do what I though was being asked:

namely to reduce an elapsed period of milliseconds to **either** (rounded) days **OR** (rounded) hours **OR** (rounded) minutes **OR** (rounded) seconds - dependent on which fits the scale of the elapsed duration (as one might want to do where, for example, a page is to report *"comment made 2 days ago"* or *"comment made 10 seconds ago"* etc. - just like SO does when reporting when answers or comments were made.

As with the accepted answer, the **elapsed** time has to first be calculated by subtracting the passed ms value from a new date value (and, since units smaller than seconds will never be needed, the elapsed value converted to seconds by dividing by 1000):

```
const now = new Date();
const secondsPast = Math.round((now-pastMs)/1000);
```

This value is then filtered down a series of `if` checks, each containing a conditional `return` statement if the relevant time unit has been reached. Thus, if the 'scale' is seconds (i.e the elapsed duration is less than a minute), the function returns the seconds value and exits immeadiately:

```
if (secondsPast<60) {return `${secondsPast} seconds`} // terminates here if true;
```

If the seconds value is greater than 60, minutes are checked and a return made if they are less than sixty. The process repeats until larger values are eventually returned as days if no other unit was appropriate. Note the use of `Math.floor` to only return whole numbers for the relevant unit.

(this is, I think, what the original question was trying to achieve).

```js
function elapsedTime(pastMs) {
  const now = new Date();
  const secondsPast = Math.round((now-pastMs)/1000);
  
    if (secondsPast<60) {return `${secondsPast} seconds`} // terminates here if true;
    
  const minutesPast = Math.floor(secondsPast/60);
    if (minutesPast<60) {return `${minutesPast} minutes`} // terminates here if true;
    
  const hoursPast = Math.floor(minutesPast/60);
    if (hoursPast<24) {return `${hoursPast} hours`} // terminates here if true;
    
  return `${Math.floor(hoursPast/24)} days`;
  
} // end function elapsedTime;
    
console.log(elapsedTime(1653991056493))
```